# Notepad++ macro not working correctly

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have the TextFX plugin, and one of its functions is convert text to proper case.

I used the shortcut mapper and set the shortcut in the plugin commands tab.

The shortcut works without an issue but when I record it as a macro I get something that looks more like a serialized export.

[image]

Can anyone help me get this working?

Cheers

Comment: I had done this too and it worked without problems. The only thing I can think of is that some other command is bound to the same shortcut: delete the shortcut and see if the weird behaviour is still there, if yes: look through all pages of the shortcut mapper if you can see the shortcut somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I have checked each line and tab in the shortcut mapper without finding a conflict.
I also removed all the shortcuts that I had previously set and used the same key combination to test to ensure no shortcuts were bound to them all without success.